# How to add a scale bar or axis to a scatter plot?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, axis, scatter-plot

I wrote some code that plots coordinates onto a drawing area (`JPanel`). here is my code class:

```
class POSCanvas extends JPanel {
    private XYSeries pnts = new XYSeries("Position");

    public POSCanvas() {
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
        this.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void update(double xnew, double ynew) {
        pnts.add(new XYDataItem(xnew, ynew));
    }

    private ChartPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            "", "X", "Y", createSampleData(),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
        XYItemRenderer renderer = xyPlot.getRenderer();
        NumberAxis domain = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
        int minX = (int)pnts.getMinX(); int maxX = (int)pnts.getMaxX();
        if (minX < maxX){domain.setRange(minX, maxX);}
        domain.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1));
        NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1));
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        };
    }

    private XYDataset createSampleData() {
        XYSeriesCollection xySeriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection();
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(pnts);
        return xySeriesCollection;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can not seem to add the range for the X axis. Here is the output:
[image]

I am using the `domain.setRange()` method but it does not work. Any idea how to fix it? Any help would be appreciated; thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`ChartFactory.createScatterPlot()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createScatterPlot-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset-), which "uses an `XYPlot` instance as the plot, with a `NumberAxi`s for the domain axis, a `NumberAxis` as the range axis, and an `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` as the renderer." Several complete examples are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20ChartFactory.createScatterPlot), and the factory's [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1657) is included in the distribution.

[image]

Comment: i have switched to JFreechart. it creates the y axis but does not create the X axis. any idea why is that?

Comment: What happens if you don't change `domain`? A [mcve] would make it easier to test.